# Excel: Extracting data based on range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table for the number of products sold:
[image]

I have another table that calculates the cumulative product sold

[image]

I have a price table based on # of product sold:

[image]

What equation should I write to get the cost price of the product based on cumulative data? Basically, as the cumulative product for category A is less than 10 till 2022 the multiplier price is $5 but in 2023 as the cumulative product is more than 10 the multiplier is $3.
[image]

Please know that the actual data set has a price multiplier for multiple range and the number of products sold is in million. The above is just a sample.

Comment: First work out the cumulative total, probably using VLOOKUP. Then use the MATCH function to determine the applicable price.

Comment: @Variatus, thank you for the reply. follow-up question: If I have millions of products sold then the match function would have to look into a table with the product column extending up to a million in number. Is this correct? If so is there any other way to do this?

Comment: This is a Q&A forum. One question. One answer. No follow-up. But the next question is free. I thought your question related to a task in school. But, yes, it should be done the same way. And no, there is no reason to change the method because the db is big.

Answer (score 0):

Lose the `<` character in the Item column of the price table. Then you can use it for an approximate lookup.

Let's say the price table is on a sheet called PriceSheet and starts in cell A1, so the first row of data is in row 2. The price table must be sorted ascending by the first column. To look up the price use

```
=vlookup(A1,PriceSheet!$A$2:$B$5,2,1)
```

Multiply that with the count.

```
=A1*vlookup(A1,PriceSheet!$A$2:$B$5,2,1)
```

Now just change `A1` to the cell that has the cumulative count.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Vlookup needs an exact match. If I replace A1 within Vlookup to cumulative count than my price table should have a value for this A1. The problem is if the price table extends all the way to say 1M product then I have would have to have a column containing 1 to 1M  products (across rows) and the price for each # of product.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. "Vlookup needs an exact match" - What do you mean with that? Vlookup can look up approximate matches, but the lookup table needs to be sorted by the first column. If the table has the values `10,20,30` etc in the first column, you can look up the price for `25`. The last parameter of the Vlookup function then needs to be `True` or `1`, as in my formula. It will return the item for the number that is **equal or less than** the lookup value. Please take a look at the documentation. I don't feel like writing it all down here.